# rm -f in a script

Tags: scripting

Here is my script:

```
[root@hostname ~]# cat ontape.sh
#!/bin/bash
#

sshpass -p 'PASSWORD' ssh root@hostname mkdir -p /home/mybackup/ontape/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

sshpass -p 'PASSWORD' ssh root@hostname mkdir -p /mybackup/ontape_tmp_backup/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

for server in $(cat servers.txt)

do

 sshpass -p 'PASSWORD' scp /dbbackup/backupdb/ontape/fullsize/* $server/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"

rm -f /dbbackup/backupdb/ontape/fullsize/* 

done
```

The problem I am having is when this runs it copies only to the one server because it does the `rm -f` right after it finishes. Is there a way or how can I add a wait in there so it takes time to copy to both servers before deleting the file?

Answer (score 2):

Just put the `rm -f` line outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `rm -f` to after the `done` line (so that it's the last line of the script), that way the directory is emptied when the loop finishes and the files have been copied to all servers.

Comment: Ok thank just tried that and it worked great. thank you for you assistance. I have posted something about running this script local and it worked great however when I ran as a cronjob over the weekend I got an erorr message like this. cat: servers1.txt: No such file or directory -- any idea why i would get this when running cronjob? I don't get errors running locally at all.

Comment: @D.F. your `servers1.txt` doesn't exist in the `$HOME` directory of whatever user is running the `cron` job.

Comment: @D.F. Specify the full path of the `servers1.txt` file in the script or use `cd` in the script to move to the correct location where it's located.

Comment: Please see this .. [root@local ~]# pwd
/root
[root@local ~]# ls -l servers*
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 69 Aug 18 13:06 servers1.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 75 Aug 18 12:19 servers.txt

Comment: @D.F. In the script, use `/root/servers1.txt` rather than just `servers1.txt`, or put `cd /root` at the beginning of the script before you try to access the file.  I'm assuming that you run this from `root`'s crontab and not from the crontab of some other user (in which case they would not have access to the `/root` directory).

Comment: here is what I did. SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/root       ( I changed the home from / to /root and then ran it and it worked is that okay to do?

Comment: @D.F. It is ok to do as long as it does not affect any other cron jobs. It would be safer to use the absolute path of the file in the script. Changing `$HOME` in the crontab affects _all_ jobs in that crontab.

Comment: I used absoulte paths and got it to work. I do have one last question is there a way to get this files to copy simultaneously? Right now it copies to one server then when finishes copies to the next it work, however just thinking there is a better way any thoughts?

Comment: @D.F. Add a single `&` at the very end of the `scp` line, then add the word `wait` just before `rm -f`, after the loop.  This will start the `scp` command as concurrent background jobs, and the `wait` will wait for all of them to finish.

Comment: is there a way to get the files to sync up on all servers the same time instead of using scp what would the syntax be fro rsync?